# One output from one array and different output from an array which is nested inside

Tags: reactjs, for-loop

I have two arrays configuration and sensordata, I want `div` elements to get displayed when there is a match otherwise another `div` elements.

```
//configuration is the first loop 
        this.props.configuration.forEach((wheel, index) => {
     // sensor data is the nested loop      
        this.props.sensorData.forEach((sensor) => {
                if (wheel.wheel) {
    //Here I am checking if wheel doesn't exists in sensor
                  if(wheel.wheel!=sensor.sub_item)
                  axles.push( //divs to get displayed
                    <div className='twoaxlewheels' id={axleIndex}>
                      <span className='infotype' id={wheel.wheel}>9 Bar 16 Pressure</span>
                      <span className='TyreImage' id={wheel.wheel}><img src={tyre5} /> </span>
                    </div>)
    //If wheel exist in sensor 
                  if (sensor.sub_item == wheel.wheel) {
                    axles.push( //divs to get displayed
                      <div className='twoaxlewheels' id={axleIndex}>
                        <span className='infotype' id={wheel.wheel}>{wheel.wheel == sensor.sub_item ? sensor.temp : ''}</span>
                        <span className='TyreImage' id={wheel.wheel}>{wheel.wheel == sensor.sub_item ? <img src={tyre5} /> : ''} </span>
                      </div>)
                  }
                }
              })
            return axles //returning axles here
            })
```

With above code I am looping multiple times. I couldn't loop it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand well, your issue is with the conditional rendering ? To display JSX when a condition is true ?
(https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

If that's the case, you can do in the return of your function, like :

```
return (<>
{this.props.sensorData.forEach((sensor) => {
   wheel.wheel != sensor.sub_item ? (<div className='twoaxlewheels' id={axleIndex}>
                      <span className='infotype' id={wheel.wheel}>9 Bar 16 Pressure</span>
                      <span className='TyreImage' id={wheel.wheel}><img src={tyre5} /> </span>
                    </div>) : ( <div className='twoaxlewheels' id={axleIndex}>
                        <span className='infotype' id={wheel.wheel}>{wheel.wheel == sensor.sub_item ? sensor.temp : ''}</span>
                        <span className='TyreImage' id={wheel.wheel}>{wheel.wheel == sensor.sub_item ? <img src={tyre5} /> : ''} </span>
                      </div>)</>}
```

Comment: Since its getting harder to do that way,I simplified to do it in this way    configuration.forEach((e1) => sensorData.forEach((e2) => {
      if (e1.wheel == e2.sub_item) {
        finalarray.push(e1)
        finalarray.push(e2)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(finalarray))
      }
    }
    ))   Even in this scenario I am trying to merge both arrays based on the condition into a single array,I am getting two separate arrays in finalarray